# how to set android splash screen using config.xml of cordova2.6

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

I am using cordova2.6 for my app. I can set splash screen using the SplashScreen api comes with cordova. That works fine too but when I tried to use

```
<gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
```

inside the config.xml, it says "gap" is an undefined prefix and throws error. can someone explain what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your Android App folder go to the `res` folder and put the splashscreen inside 
`drawable 
drawable-hdpi 
drawable-mdpi 
...`
 folders with good size :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have problem in  tag definition. Do you have this property:
 xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"