# Android - phonegap error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: java, javascript, xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I restarted eclipse and the error changed to "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix" on the same line

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/javamrright/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/4a00843982ed07a34a592f6556b6d8056f6dca92) plugin in my android phonegap application. It is a local notification plugin. I am getting the error in my config.xml file on this line:

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" version="0.6.2" />
```

There is a similar question about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189621/how-to-set-android-splash-screen-using-config-xml-of-cordova2-6), but the answer is not related to my problem.

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "com.xxx.xxx"
        version   = "2.0.0">
    <name>xxx</name>

    <description>
    xxx
    </description>

    <author href="http://www.example.com" email="xxx@yahoo.com">
    xxx
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>

    <!-- <content src="xxx" /> for external pages -->
    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    -->

    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Storage">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->


    <plugins>
        <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
        <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" version="0.6.2" />
    </plugins>

</widget>
```

I am using eclipse with the adt plugin. I generated an android application and made some modification to it so it would work with phonegap (its working fine without the local notification plugin). I am using cordova 2.9.0 version.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Show us the error message

Comment: and also how you are trying to add the plugin, what version of phonegap youy are using, are you using phonegap build, the CLI... If you want help, you should be more precise about what you're doing.

Comment: I just updated  my question.

Comment: Did you add permission to AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yes. For now I have the full list of permissions.

Comment: UPDATE: I restarted eclipse and the error changed to "error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix" on the same line

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to add a xml namespace.

```
  xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
```

Your root xml schould look like this one:

```
  <widget id="com.example.MyApp" 
    version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

good luck!

Comment: For `android:something` properties (like the example shown in @mrmoree's answer), add the following to the `<widget>` tag: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Comment: @drdrej  Hi i am using  <gap:plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" version="3.1.8" />
so what wil i write in widget??

Answer (score 18):

For me the problem was a not interpretable attribute in my manifest file. 
change the red marked to the green one (see screenshot), make sure you have your android device connected and run `phonegap run android` again.

[image: change wrong xml attributes in AndroidManifest.xml]

**Use adb logcat to discover build and runtime issues**
For android you can use the logcat output to debug your phonegap/cordova application.
On iOS use the logcat output from xcode

i discovered the above problem by running `adb logcat` from projects root in console.

if you like to filter the output of any logfile you can do easily by using `grep` followed by your keyword (e.g. error or mergemanifest):

```
adb logcat | grep error
```

replace "error" with whatever you are looking for in logcat

Comment: Or just add the android namespace to your xml  `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: The namespace suggestion by David is what was needed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much [mrmoree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2828913/mrmoree)! This thread pointed me in the right direction. I had an similar issue with the final version of the config.xml being built by ionic-cordova, getting this error:

> .../platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml:51: AAPT: error:
>   unbound prefix.

I had to switch over the xml tag format to have `name="android.permission.CAMERA" platform="android"` broken out instead of `android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"` for it to work. Now it works great.

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.CAMERA" platform="android" />
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" platform="android" />
        <uses-permission name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" platform="android" />
    </config-file>
</platform>
```