# android cordova phonegap config.xml unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have the following config.xml file for my android app, and I am trying to install launchmyapp plugin. Everytime I clean, I get this the following error

```
/code/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:21: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

I checked other stack questions and everyone is pointing to wrong formatting in the parameter fields, but all seems ok...

here is the config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.myappname.Myappname" version="2.2.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyAppName</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
        <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp">
        <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="myappname" />
    </gap:plugin>
</widget>
```

Comment: Could be duplicated with thread [Android - phonegap error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115471/android-phonegap-error-error-parsing-xml-unbound-prefix)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've encountered the same question as yours. I supposed it's because 
`<gap:plugin>` must be bound to phonegap prefix.

So I solved this question by adding `xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"` at  node.

In your case, the full `<widget>` should be:

```
<widget id="com.myappname.Myappname" version="2.2.3"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

Hope it works for you.